# Find profile path in native messaging host

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a native messaging host and want to find the profile path of the extension that launched it.

I have tried using `NtQueryInformationProcess` to retrieve the command line of the calling process (which has the profile path), however it appears I'm not always able to obtain the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege which is necessary to read the process memory.

Other than using `NPAPI` (because it is going away), any other ideas on how this can be obtained?

Comment: If I may be so bold: why are you trying to do this? what's the goal here?

Comment: Sorry FuzzyAmi, just noticed your comment.  I wanted the path so the native messaging app could read other files that are included with the extension.  I resorted to reading the file from the extension and sending the entire file over the native messaging pipe.